# How to add pagination to a custom Word Press loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination

This is my code here -

```
    <div class="gallery-posts">
        <?php
            $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'numberposts' => 4
                );
            $product_posts = get_posts( $args ); 
        ?>
        <?php foreach ( $product_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>    
            <?php $videos = rwmb_meta( '_video-link' );
                    foreach ( $videos as $video ); ?>   
                <div 
                class="card-container video-link" 
                data-link="<?php echo $video['src']; ?>" 
                title="<?php the_title(); ?>"
                description="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_description', true ) ); ?>"
                thumbnail-link="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url()  ?>">
                    <figure class="gallery-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <div class="gallery-image-text">
                            <p><?php the_title() ?></p>
                            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                        </div>
                    </figure>
                    </div>
        <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

I want to set it up so that Next/Prev shows whenever there are more than 4 posts.

With the regular Word Press loop I know you can just do the_posts_pagination but that doesn't work here.

What needs to be added for pagination to work with this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
<div class="gallery-posts">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'paged' => $paged
            );
        $product_posts = get_posts( $args ); 
        foreach ( $product_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
            $videos = rwmb_meta( '_video-link' );
            foreach ( $videos as $video ):
            ?>
            <div class="card-container video-link" data-link="<?php echo $video['src']; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"  description="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_description', true ) ); ?>" thumbnail-link="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url()  ?>">
                <figure class="gallery-image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <div class="gallery-image-text">
                        <p><?php the_title() ?></p>
                        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                    </div>
                </figure>
                </div>
            <?php
            
            next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $product_posts->max_num_pages );
            previous_posts_link( 'Next Entries &raquo;' );
            wp_reset_postdata();
            endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
```